# Enforce upper bound for R Package version dependency

Tags: r, r-package

When developing R packages, we use the DESCRIPTION file to list package dependencies (e.g. in the "Imports" section) and we're allowed to specify a **minimum** version required for each package dependency by suffixing with "(>= x.x.x)". However, what is the analogous feature to specify the **maximum** version?

#### Some context

Sometimes the external packages that we depend are released with *breaking changes* that may no longer be compatible with the package being developed. Updating our package each time external packages are updated with breaking changes isn't sustainable.

#### Example

Let's say I'm developing an R package called "MarksPackage" and it depends on "dplyr". Everything that I've built so far works just fine with the current state of dplyr v1. However, tomorrow dplyr v2 is released with *breaking changes* that affect my package. For new users that are insalling my package may have installed the latest dplyr v2 and so MarksPackage won't work for them.
I don't necessarily want to or am able to go update my package each time dplyr is updated with breaking changes. I'd rather specify a maximum version, or even a version range, for which I know MarksPackage will work.

How do I accomplish this within the DESCRIPTION file? Is there a syntax like:

```
Package: MarksPackage
Imports: 
    dplyr (>= 0.8.5 & <=1.2.0),
    dbplyr,
    tidyr (<= 1.0.2)
```

Comment: I think in general newer packages should not break. That is the purpose of that testing, declaring as deprecated etc., isn't it? And if there are breaking changes, changing your package (e.g. removing the dependency) is the way to go IMHO.

Comment: I agree with @KarstenW. about the best practice; you should change with the times. However, I have an answer on the technical "how" part of the question below without touching on the "should" part (what you *should* do)

Comment: @KarstenW. I understand where you're coming from and I typically agree. However, our organization has a funny way of working and while this maybe not the best practice, we needed this ability in one particular instance (and hence I tried justifying it with my Context section). For example, we roughly know that once we develop this package internally, it won't get touched again and so I really want it to be "set it and forget it" and have a guarnatee that it'll be crystal clear for future users how to create an environment that's guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have a question about how R extension packages work, you should consult the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual.
Here in particular, you want [Section 1.1.3, Package Dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies), which explains in relevant part

> The ‘Depends’ field gives a comma-separated list of package names which this package depends on. Those packages will be attached before the current package when library or require is called. Each package name may be optionally followed by a comment in parentheses specifying a version requirement. The comment should contain a comparison operator, whitespace and a valid version number, e.g. ‘MASS (>= 3.1-20)’.
>
> ...
>
> A package or ‘R’ can appear more than once in the ‘Depends’ field, for example to give upper and lower bounds on acceptable versions.

So, for your example, you'd do

```
Package: MarksPackage
Imports: 
    dplyr (>= 0.8.5),
    dplyr (<= 1.2.0),
    dbplyr,
    tidyr (<= 1.0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I missed in the documentation. I wish this had made it into the Hadley bookdowns... I almost never reference the original docs

Comment: Yeah, and to be fair @mkirzon those original docs are pretty lengthy and most of it doesn't apply to what you need at any given time, so I can't fully blame you for not having read through them. But, now having been someone who has read through (most) parts of the manual a few times, I would actually say that surprisingly it's pretty worthwhile to do at some point